# Does hitting time have scaling property or self-similar proerty

Tags: probability, stopping-times

Consider the hitting time such that $\tau_x = \inf\{t>0: B_t = x\}$ where $B_t$ is a standard brownian motion. Can $\tau_x$ be scaled like that $\tau_{ax}=a^2\tau_x$ for $\forall a>0, a\in \mathbb R $? I have checked the probability density function of $\tau_x$ satisfy the scaling property since $f_{\tau_{x}}(t)=\frac{|x|e^{-\frac{x^2}{2t}}} { \sqrt{2\pi}t^{\frac{3}{2}}}$ and it can be proved that $f_{\tau_{ax}}(t)=\frac{|ax|e^{-\frac{(ax)^2}{2t}}} { \sqrt{2\pi}t^{\frac{3}{2}}}=a^{-3}\frac{a|x|e^{-\frac{(x)^2}{2t/a^2}}} { \sqrt{2\pi}(\frac{t}{a^2})^{\frac{3}{2}}}=a^{-2}f_{\tau_{x}}(\frac{t}{a^2})$. Did I make any mistakes on these?

Comment: Well, since you know the pdf of $\tau_x$ you can obviously use it to verify the scaling property... nothing wrong about that. However, it's kind of overkill; it would be more natural to use the scaling property of $(B_t)_{t \geq 0}$.

Comment: Thx, I also verify that by using the Brownian scaling. The interesting thing is that when you scale the stopping time and embed it into the Brownian motion. It would become a different thing.